# databricks cli to update job shcedule

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I have configured the Databricks cli locally and able to connect to the Azure Databricks cluster. Link reference used for my workstation - [git](https://github.com/thirumurthis/Learnings/blob/master/Azure_databricks_python/Locally_connecting_to_Databricks_cluster.md)

- Below command list the jobs successfully with the id

```
$ databricks jobs list --profile dev
```

Say if I wanted to update only the schedule (cron expression) to a specific job which is already deployed in workspace, i don't see any option to do it using databricks CLI.

Note: In my case the the jobs are created using job definition json, is used to create the jobs in the cluster. This json doesn't have the schedule info to start with.

Is there are any options available to update only schedule, after the job is created or deployed in the workspace?

There is an option to run the command immediately, `databricks jobs run-now`.

The REST API configuration
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsCreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Databricks jobs CLI supports calls to two versions of the
> Databricks Jobs REST API: versions 2.1 and 2.0. Version 2.1 adds
> support for orchestration of jobs with multiple tasks; see [Jobs with
> multiple
> tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/)
> and [Jobs API
> updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs-api-updates).

Going through the MS docs I see, you can use the update request to change an existing job.

```
databricks jobs update --job-id 246 --json-file update-job.json
```

schedule information block in the input json file.

```
"schedule": {
      "quartz_cron_expression": "0 0 0 * * ?",
      "timezone_id": "US/Pacific",
      "pause_status": "UNPAUSED"
    }
```

Refer: [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs-api-updates#:%7E:text=An%20example%20JSON%20document%20representing%20a%20single%2Dtask%20format%20job%20for%20API%202.0%3A) - An example JSON document representing a single-task format job for API 2.0:

```
{
  "job_id": 27,
  "settings": {
    "name": "Example notebook",
    "existing_cluster_id": "1201-my-cluster",
    "libraries": [
      {
        "jar": "dbfs:/FileStore/jars/spark_examples.jar"
      }
    ],
    "email_notifications": {},
    "timeout_seconds": 0,
    "schedule": {
      "quartz_cron_expression": "0 0 0 * * ?",
      "timezone_id": "US/Pacific",
      "pause_status": "UNPAUSED"
    },
    "notebook_task": {
      "notebook_path": "/notebooks/example-notebook",
      "revision_timestamp": 0
    },
    "max_concurrent_runs": 1,
    "format": "SINGLE_TASK"
  },
  "created_time": 1504128821443,
  "creator_user_name": "user@databricks.com"
}
```

Comment: Ok. Using JSON definition the job schedule can be updated. Was looking for option like $ databricks jobs update --job-id 246 --schedule '0 0 0 ...'.

Comment: Datbricks jobs cli does not have the option `update`. use `databricks jobs reset` to update jobs.

Answer (score 3):

#### UPDATE

Databricks has release a new version of their CLI which is backward incompatible ([more details on migration](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/migrate.html))
The *new* version is >= `0.205` (last legacy <= `0.18`)

In the new CLI the commands look like:

```
databricks jobs get 1234 > my-job.json

# my-job.json should contain the job_id parameter
databricks jobs reset --json @path/to/my-job.json
```

---

Original answer for legacy version of CLI.

To update the job use the `databricks jobs reset` command.

[Databricks Azure jobs CLI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/jobs-cli#change-settings-for-a-job)

Documentation claims that partial updates are possible, but whenever I try to only update the schedule it complains about parameters missing.

A way around it is to read the job settings first and then editing the job json before updating:

```
databricks jobs get --job-id 1234 > my-job.json
```

then update the `my-job.json` and use it with `reset` command:

```
databricks jobs reset --job-id 1234 --json-file my-job.json
```

Comment: I noticed the same "parameters missing" issue when I tried to use the `reset` command. I have created an issue on databricks cli repo, please upvote - https://github.com/databricks/databricks-cli/issues/606#issuecomment-1446074865

Comment: This version of CLI is now deprecated.

Comment: @Kashyap I added an update regarding the new CLI

Answer (score 0):

Using the jobs update command of [new version of databricks cli](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/install.html), which [follows REST API docs](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/update):

E.g. following will update the `schedule` for job with id `1234567890`:

```bash
databricks jobs update --json '
{
  "job_id": 1234567890,
  "new_settings": {
    "schedule": {
      "pause_status": "PAUSED",
      "quartz_cron_expression": "0 0 3 1 1,4,7,10 ?",
      "timezone_id": "America/New_York"
    }
  }
}
'
```

---

You can:

1. list jobs using `databricks jobs list`
2. get a job's current settings/json using `databricks jobs get <job-id>`
3. update any top level element by placing them under `new_settings` and calling `databricks jobs update`.
4. Use databricks jobs update with `new-settings` to update "any top level element" of the json you get from `databricks jobs get ...`.

---

Following will pause all jobs (i.e. change the `"pause_status"` to `"PAUSED"`) whose name match pattern `'job-name-pattern'`

[Uses jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/).

```bash
for j in `databricks jobs list | grep 'job-name-pattern' | awk '{print $1}'`
do
  echo $j
  databricks jobs get $j | jq '{"job_id": .job_id, "new_settings": {"schedule": {"pause_status": "PAUSED", "quartz_cron_expression": .settings.schedule.quartz_cron_expression, "timezone_id": .settings.schedule.timezone_id}}}' > /tmp/new_${j}_settings.json
  cat /tmp/new_${j}_settings.json
  databricks jobs update --json @/tmp/new_${j}_settings.json &
done

echo waiting..
wait

rm /tmp/new_*_settings.json
```